# prevent height sizing at design time

Tags: c#, class-design

I'm working on a custom user control.  How can I prevent the HEIGHT ONLY of the control from being modified during the design-time interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [`SetBoundsCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore.aspx) method and disallow changes to height by changing the `height` value before calling the base class implementation.

```
private const int FixedHeightIWantToKeep = 100;

protected override void SetBoundsCore(
    int x,
    int y,
    int width,
    int height,
    BoundsSpecified specified)
{
    // Fixes height at 100 (or whatever fixed height is set to).
    height = this.FixedHeightIWantToKeep;
    base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Height attribute from the Control class and then set the [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) to prevent it from being displayed in the properties windows

You can also take a look at [Attributes and Design-Time Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19191fh.aspx)